# How to use Node 8 inspector with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I am familiar with using the `--inspect` option since node 7 or something. Now on node 8, it's just not working. Today I asked node to use the inspector, as usual:

```
$ node --inspect --debug-brk node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha o/**/*.test.js
```

It responds with this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/97a6264d-a751-4467-ac36-172ff3ebaac1
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

If I try to open that link, Chrome says:

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at ws://127.0.0.1:9229/97a6264d-a751-4467-ac36-172ff3ebaac1 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME
```

Before it used to be a "chrome-devtools://" link, which worked splendidly.

What gives?

Searching around, I can't find anything I'm supposed to do with this `ws://` link.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is [information](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/#chrome-devtools-55) from nodejs docs

> Option 1: Open `chrome://inspect` in a Chromium-based browser. Click
>   the Configure button and ensure your target host and port are listed.
>   Then select your Node.js app from the list.
>
> Option 2: Install the
>   Chrome Extension [NIM (Node Inspector Manager)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj)

I prefer option 2.

Also `--debug-brk` is deprecated. Node.js 8.x uses `--inspect-brk`

Comment: Thanks so much! I used `node --inspect --inspect-brk node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha o/**/*.test.js` and visited `chrome://inspect` — and it worked like a charm

Comment: If you use custom port you should add this port to "Discover network targets"

Comment: OMG you're a lifesaver. Thank you!