# How to solve chrome ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME when opening wss protocol？

Tags: node.js, inspect

I run node cli `node --inspect start/server`

Which `start/server` is a koa2 webserver.

and then I got:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/3323c837-cc74-4897-af12-8fccc9d709c1
```

I got bellow in chrome when I input ws url:

```
ws://127.0.0.1:9229/3323c837-cc74-4897-af12-8fccc9d709c1:1 GET ws://127.0.0.1:9229/3323c837-cc74-4897-af12-8fccc9d709c1 net::ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME
```

How can I solve the `net::ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Node 8 inspector with Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750727/how-to-use-node-8-inspector-with-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Chrome Browser:

1. enter chrome://flags/ in your browser url
2. enable #allow-insecure-localhost
3. restart browser

that worked for me!

Comment: I just did this and it failed at my end... The Network Inspector shows the WSS connection with HTTP 101 status.

Answer (score 2):

Just type in Chrome about:inspect
then Open dedicated DevTools for Node

Answer (score -1):

If you are using websocket like webRTC, then check the headset/sound settings. That resolved my issue